# Proving the multiplicative property of limits.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) =L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x) =M$ then prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)g(x) =LM$

**Attempt**

(Should there be any statement that I should write at start of this proof?)
 $$|f(x)g(x) -LM|=|f(x)g(x)+Lg(x)-Lg(x) -LM|=|g(x)[f(x)-L]+L[g(x)-M]<|g(x)|f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that 
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2g(x)}~~ whenever~~ 0<|x-a|<\delta_1$$
$$|g(x)-M|<\frac{\epsilon}{2L}~~ whenever~~ 0<|x-a|<\delta_2$$

Choose $0<|x-a|<\delta$ where $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then we have
 $$|f(x)g(x) -LM|<\epsilon$$

Is this proof correct?

The reason I am concerned is in the second step where I defined the inequalities for the individual expression, I wrote it in terms of $g(x)$  and $L$. Is this step mathematically correct?

Edit:

Is this continuation correct?

Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that 
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}~~ whenever~~ 0<|x-a|<\delta_1$$
$$|g(x)-M|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|L|)}~~ whenever~~ 0<|x-a|<\delta_2$$

Choose $0<|x-a|<\delta$ where $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then we have
 $$|f(x)g(x) -LM|<|g(x)|\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}+|L|\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|L|)}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed $0<\epsilon<1$. I would start from (your strict inequality in the first line of your proof is problematic)
$$
\begin{align}
&|f(x)g(x) -LM|=|f(x)g(x)+Lg(x)-Lg(x) -LM|\\
\leqslant&\ |g(x)|\cdot|f(x)-L|+|L|\cdot|g(x)-M|\\
\leqslant&\  (|g(x)-M|+|M|)\cdot|f(x)-L|+|L|\cdot|g(x)-M|
\end{align}
$$

and show the following:

- there exists $\delta_1$ such that
  $$
  |f(x)-L|<\epsilon,\quad \hbox{for all }\ 0<|x-a|<\delta_1;
  $$
- there exists $\delta_2$ such that
  $$
  |g(x)-M|<\epsilon,\quad \hbox{for all }\ 0<|x-a|<\delta_2.
  $$

By choosing the smaller one as $\delta$, one has
$$
|f(x)g(x)-LM|\leqslant (1+|M|)\epsilon +|L|\epsilon
\leqslant (1+|M|+|L|)\epsilon\tag{1}
$$
for all $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

---

[**Added**:] To see why (1) completes the proof, do the following exercise. Show that the following two statements are equivalent:

- There exists some constant $C$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$, $|A|\leqslant C\epsilon$.
- For every $\epsilon>0$, $|A|\leqslant \epsilon$.

---

**Remark**. One important tactic that is seldom mentioned in elementary real analysis textbooks is that when doing an estimate in analysis, one should never worry about the constant in front of one's epsilon. As Terry Tao points out in [one](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/) of his excellent blog posts on problem solving strategies in real analysis:

> **Don’t worry too much about exactly what $\varepsilon$ (or $\delta$, or $N$, etc.) needs to be.  It can usually be chosen or tweaked later if necessary.**

Comment: Is the statement proved? Arent we supposed to show $|f(x)g(x)-LM|<\epsilon$

Comment: Yes. This is the point of doing analysis. Let me explain later in my answer.

Comment: Is this correct? $|A|<C\epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2$

Comment: I think you get the point. Need to be a little bit more careful about the writing though.

Comment: So if I arise in such a situation such that I get $C\epsilon$ in the end. What statements should I write to show that this completes the proof? Is writing "$|A| = C\epsilon = \epsilon$ since $\epsilon $ is arbitrary" sufficient?

Comment: Suppose you have show that for any $\epsilon>0$, $|A|\leqslant C\epsilon$. For arbitrary $\epsilon'>0$, one has $\epsilon'/C>0$. Now let $\epsilon=\epsilon'/C$ to conclude that $|A|\leqslant \epsilon'$.

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. As you noticed, your $\delta_1$ also depends on $g(x)$. Besides, you *divide* by $g(x)$. What if $g(x)=0$?

Comment: So what should be replaced over there? And what about the second expression? There I divided by 2L. What should be replaced there considering L could be 0?

Comment: @FaiqRaees You should consider two cases: $M=0$ and $M\neq0$. Besides, you should find an upper bound $K$ of $g(x)$ near $a$. So, in order to prove that $|g(x)|.|f(x)-L|<\frac\epsilon2$, all you'll have to prove is that $K.|f(x)-L|<\frac\epsilon2$.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: @FaiqRaees I don't see where does the first $<$ sign from the last equality come from.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: @FaiqRaees Sorry. I meant the last line, not the last equality.

Comment: That follows from the first statement of this proof.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Yes, you are right. But how do you know that $|g(x)|\frac\epsilon{2(1+|M|)}<\frac\epsilon2$?

Comment: well because $|g(x)|<\epsilon +|M|$. So $\frac{|g(x)|}{1+|M|}<1$

Comment: @FaiqRaees So, you are assuming that $\epsilon<1$. Not an important restriction, of course, but it should be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine but a few details are not correct.

You should replace 
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2g(x)}$$
with something like
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2M'}.$$
where $M'$ is a positive constant to be decided.
Recall that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x) =M$ implies that $g$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $a$.

Moreover to avoid problems with the case when $L=0$, replace
$$|g(x)-M|<\frac{\epsilon}{2L}$$
for example with
$$|g(x)-M|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|L|)}.$$

Are you able to finish to proof correctly now?

P.S. In your edited work add th following line $|g(x)|<{(1+|M|)}$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_3$ and define $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$.

Comment: Okay what about the second expression? There I divided by 2L. Would should be replaced there considering L could be 0?

Comment: @Faiq Raees See my edited answer.  Are you able to finish to proof correctly now?

Comment: Yes. Please check the edit

Comment: @Faiq Raees You are almost done. Add one line $|g(x)|<{(1+|M|)}$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_3$ and $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$

Comment: Actually, I have some concerns over this substitution. We are working on the greater side of inequality. If we substitute something that is greater than gx as denominator, it will make the fraction smaller, and the ineqaulity might not hold anymore.

Comment: @Faiq Raees In the last step you substitute $|g(x)|$ with $(1+|M|)$ and $|g(x)|$ is at the numerator. The problem that you are talking about is when you consider the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$. In that case you need  a bound for $|g(x)|$ from below (therefore it is necessary that $M\not=0$).

Comment: I am talking about $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2g(x)}$ Here instead of writing $g(x)$, we write $1+|M|$ which is obviously greater than $g(x)$, it will make the fraction smaller and the inequality might not hold.

Comment: Nevermind, Got it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Faiq Raees We decided not to use $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2g(x)}$, did we? In fact we replaced it with $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|M|)}$. Note that this last inequality does not imply the first one (which is not useful at all here).

Comment: Yes yes I thought we were substituting $1+|M|$ in place of $g(x)$ whereas that's not the case.